# Google sheets - sum all the numbers in a cell with text, but excluding URL's

Tags: regex, google-sheets, split, formula, spreadsheet

I have a column in a Google Sheets spreadsheet containing text and numbers, and also URL's, and I need to sum up all the numbers in another column. Since this is the format the client wants to use, it is not an option to split the information in more than one column.
So, the information in a cell (say, A1) is like:

```
Facebook: 1500 followers  
https://facebook.com/user/AccountName/  
Twitter: 2000 followers  
https://twitter.com/AccountName/
```

Now, in B1 I have the formula from [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/65987/extract-and-sum-numbers-from-a-cell-containing-text-that-contains-numbers)

```
=SUM(SPLIT(AE4,CONCATENATE(SPLIT(A1,".0123456789"))))
```

which is working well, unless if the URL has any number. For example the code above gives me 3500, which is correct. But if the URL has numbers, like `https://linkedin.com/user/a4df65b1`, in that case I would get 3570, that is 1500+2000+4+65+1. The formula is taking the numbers in the URL and adding them up as well.

I tried the following code also:

```
=SUM(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1, "[^\d\.]+", "|"), "|"))
```

even with modifications to include only the numbers between spaces (because in URLs there are no spaces, I want to add up only numbers between spaces) like the following:

```
=SUM(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1, "[^([:space:]\d[:space:])]", "|"), "|"))
```

Both are not working since they include numbers within URL's in the calculation too.

How can I filter URL's out or include only numbers that are between spaces?

Comment: Did either of the answers help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me you could just use this:

`=SUM(SPLIT(A1," ")`

All real numbers in your strings seem they will have a space before and after them; and any grouping that isn't a real number will be ignored by `SUM`.

Comment: That it, it doesn't get simpler than that. You can add \n into the split character edge to catch numbers at the end or start of a line too. Well done

Comment: Thanks, JvdV. As I always tell people, we can only go on what we see. And in the single example given, the pattern implies that all such cells will have a space before and after and numbers. But as you've indicated, if that turns out not to be the case, it'd be easy enough to add a line-break code and a split-by-each parameter.

Comment: Thanks, Erik! It was just as simple!
I tried and it worked perfect, no matter the URL has numbers or not.
You certainly smashed it!

Comment: Always glad to be able to keep things simple.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the URLs in your document go up till a whitespace or end of string, you may remove them and non-digits with periods using

```
=SUM(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1, "https?://\S*|[^\d.]", "|"), "|"))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/V67qg2/1).

*Details*

- `https?://\S*` - `http`, an optional `s`, `://` and then zero or more non-whitespace chars
- `|` - or
- `[^\d.]` - any char other than a digit and `.`.